# Problem with utf8 adding color headers with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, miktex, fancyhdr, unicode, poetry

I'm making a book of poems and I'd like to add some specif style to the pages. So I use `fancyhdr` And everything goes right until I add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

This is the code I use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\input{Recursos/poem-template.tex}


% aqui definimos el encabezado de las paginas pares e impares.
\lhead[x1\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-50,-693){\includegraphics[width=0.125in,height=11in]{Gráficos/orange.png}} \end{picture}]{x2}
\chead[y1]{y2}
\rhead[z1]{z2\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(50,-693){\includegraphics[width=0.125in,height=11in]{Gráficos/orange.png}} \end{picture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% aqui definimos el encabezado y pie de pagina de la pagina inicial de un capitulo.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[L]{K1\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-106,-75){\includegraphics[width=8.5in,height=1in]{Gráficos/orange.png}K1} \end{picture}}
    \fancyhead[C]{K2}
    \fancyhead[R]{K3}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\large\scshape\centering}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}

\poem{Poem-sample}{dd/mm/aaaa}{poem-sample.tex}

\end{document}
```

This is the file `poem-sample.tex`

```
\centering
Proin laoreet 
felis vitae 
mollis volutpat.

In ac dolor id
nulla consectetur faucibus.

Nam ultrices mi non 
quam tempor tristique.

Aenean sed urna dapibus, 
hendrerit magna non,
porttitor sapien.

Vivamus sed lorem 
sit amet est 
scelerisque mattis.
Ut ac elit at dui 
feugiat pulvinar.

Etiam efficitur 
ex in facilisis porta.
Mauris viverra libero 
nec justo ullamcorper, 
ac laoreet odio ultrices.

Fusce in odio at erat 
pharetra hendrerit.

Praesent fringilla 
erat ut velit pellentesque, 
nec bibendum mi lobortis.

Aliquam convallis 
enim vel convallis ornare.

In molestie mauris
quis enim ornare efficitur.

Cras faucibus tellus 
eu justo tincidunt varius.

Aenean vel risus 
ac urna vehicula mollis 
in sit amet justo.

Praesent nec nulla 
id purus hendrerit 
efficitur ac vel felis.
```

And this is the `poem-template.tex`

```
\newcommand{\poem}[3]{\chapter{#1}\centering\small\textit{#2}\\[0.05in]\normalsize\verseinput{"Contenido/texto/#3"}}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode13\active%
\gdef\verseinput#1{%
{%
\interlinepenalty\@M%
\def^^M{\@ifnextchar^^M\par{\ifhmode\break\fi}}%
\rightskip\fill%
\parindent\z@%
\parskip\baselineskip%
\raggedbottom%
\catcode13\active\input{#1}%
\par%
}}%
\endgroup%
```

I'm using MiKTeX, I think it is the problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I use MiKTeX with `utf8` encoding, and typed a few poems , and never had a problem…

Comment: Thaks! The problem is not with the poems, it is with the image in headers. But I don't know why.

Comment: And what is the `poem-template` file?

Comment: poem-template is the last code, thanks I already found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is a problem for your code.

The real problem is that you have non ascii signs in your file path, for example: `Gráficos/orange.png`.

With the following MWE I can run your code without errors or warnings. I just deactivated your faulty path for the graphic files with option `[demo]` for package `graphicx`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{poem-sample.tex}
\centering
Proin laoreet 
felis vitae 
mollis volutpat.

In ac dolor id
nulla consectetur faucibus.

Nam ultrices mi non 
quam tempor tristique.

Aenean sed urna dapibus, 
hendrerit magna non,
porttitor sapien.

Vivamus sed lorem 
sit amet est 
scelerisque mattis.
Ut ac elit at dui 
feugiat pulvinar.

Etiam efficitur 
ex in facilisis porta.
Mauris viverra libero 
nec justo ullamcorper, 
ac laoreet odio ultrices.

Fusce in odio at erat 
pharetra hendrerit.

Praesent fringilla 
erat ut velit pellentesque, 
nec bibendum mi lobortis.

Aliquam convallis 
enim vel convallis ornare.

In molestie mauris
quis enim ornare efficitur.

Cras faucibus tellus 
eu justo tincidunt varius.

Aenean vel risus 
ac urna vehicula mollis 
in sit amet justo.

Praesent nec nulla 
id purus hendrerit 
efficitur ac vel felis.
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\poem}[3]{\chapter{#1}\centering\small\textit{#2}\\[0.05in]\normalsize\verseinput{"#3"}}% <==============================

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode13\active%
\gdef\verseinput#1{%
{%
\interlinepenalty\@M%
\def^^M{\@ifnextchar^^M\par{\ifhmode\break\fi}}%
\rightskip\fill%
\parindent\z@%
\parskip\baselineskip%
\raggedbottom%
\catcode13\active\input{#1}%
\par%
}}%
\endgroup%


% aqui definimos el encabezado de las paginas pares e impares.
\lhead[x1\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-50,-693){\includegraphics[width=0.125in,height=11in]{Gráficos/orange.png}} \end{picture}]{x2}
\chead[y1]{y2}
\rhead[z1]{z2\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(50,-693){\includegraphics[width=0.125in,height=11in]{Gráficos/orange.png}} \end{picture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% aqui definimos el encabezado y pie de pagina de la pagina inicial de un capitulo.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[L]{K1\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-106,-75){\includegraphics[width=8.5in,height=1in]{Gráficos/orange.png}K1} \end{picture}}
    \fancyhead[C]{K2}
    \fancyhead[R]{K3}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\large\scshape\centering}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}

\poem{Poem-sample}{dd/mm/aaaa}{poem-sample.tex}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Please see that I changed your command `\poem`:

```
\newcommand{\poem}[3]{\chapter{#1}\centering\small\textit{#2}\\[0.05in]\normalsize\verseinput{"#3"}}% <==============================
```

Comment: Yeah!! It was a problem with my file path. Now everthing goes perfect. Thank you so much!